# Quadrant Queries

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures

I have almost solved this quadrant queries problem of Interviewstreet using segment trees with lazy propagation but I'm still getting wrong answer so I need help in my code.

This is the question:

Quadrant Queries

There are N points in the plane. The ith point has coordinates (xi, yi). Perform the following queries:

1. Reflect all points between point i and j both including along the X axis. This query is represented as `X i j`
2. Reflect all points between point i and j both including along the Y axis. This query is represented as `Y i j`
3. Count how many points between point i and j both including lie in each of the 4 quadrants. This query is represented as `C i j`

### Input:

The first line contains N, the number of points. N lines follow.

The ith line contains xi and yi separated by a space.

The next line contains Q the number of queries. The next Q lines contain one query each, of one of the above forms.

All indices are 1 indexed.

### Output:

Output one line for each query of the type `C i j`. The corresponding line contains 4 integers; the number of points having indices in the range [i..j] in the 1st,2nd,3rd and 4th quadrants respectively.

### Constraints:

```
1 <= N <= 100000
1 <= Q <= 100000
You may assume that no point lies on the X or the Y axis.
All (xi,yi) will fit in a 32-bit signed integer
In all queries, 1 <=i <=j <=N
```

### Sample Input:

```
4
1 1
-1 1
-1 -1
1 -1
5
C 1 4
X 2 4
C 3 4
Y 1 2
C 1 3
```

### Sample Output:

```
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0
0 2 0 1
```

### Explanation:

When a query says `X i j`, it means that take all the points between indices i and j both including and reflect those points along the X axis. The i and j here have nothing to do with the co-ordinates of the points. They are the indices. i refers to point i and j refers to point j

`C 1 4` asks you to 'Consider the set of points having index in {1,2,3,4}. Amongst those points, how many of them lie in the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th quads respectively?' The answer to this is clearly 1 1 1 1.

Next we reflect the points between indices '2 4' along the X axis. So the new coordinates are :

```
1 1
-1 -1
-1 1
1 1
```

Now `C 3 4` is 'Consider the set of points having index in {3,4}. Amongst those points, how many of them lie in the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th quads respectively?' Point 3 lies in quadrant 2 and point 4 lies in quadrant 1. So the answer is 1 1 0 0.

### Current Code

Here is my solution in c:

```
void query(int node, int b, int e, int i, int j, char ch)
{

      if(L[node][0]!=0 || L[node][1]!=0)
    {
      if(b!=e){
      L[2*node+1][0]=L[node][0];
      L[2*node+1][1]=L[node][1];
      L[2*node+2][0]=L[node][0];
      L[2*node+2][1]=L[node][1];
      }
      if(L[node][0]%2!=0)
      {
      tmp=Q[node][0];
      Q[node][0]=Q[node][3];
      Q[node][3]=tmp;

      tmp=Q[node][1];
      Q[node][1]=Q[node][2];
      Q[node][2]=tmp;
      }
      if(L[node][1]%2!=0)
      {
      tmp=Q[node][0];
      Q[node][0]=Q[node][1];
      Q[node][1]=tmp;

      tmp=Q[node][2];
      Q[node][2]=Q[node][3];
      Q[node][3]=tmp;
      }
      L[node][0]=0;
      L[node][1]=0;

    }

      if (i > e || j < b)
          return ;


      if (b >= i && e <= j)
      {
    if(ch == 'C'){
    ans[0]+=Q[node][0];
    ans[1]+=Q[node][1];
    ans[2]+=Q[node][2];
    ans[3]+=Q[node][3];
    }
    if(ch == 'X')
    {
      if(b!=e){
      L[2*node+1][0]++;
      L[2*node+2][0]++;
      }
      tmp=Q[node][0];
      Q[node][0]=Q[node][3];
      Q[node][3]=tmp;
      tmp=Q[node][1];
      Q[node][1]=Q[node][2];
      Q[node][2]=tmp;
    }
    if(ch == 'Y')
    {
      if(b!=e){
      L[2*node+1][1]++;
      L[2*node+2][1]++;
      }
      tmp=Q[node][0];
      Q[node][0]=Q[node][1];
      Q[node][1]=tmp;
      tmp=Q[node][2];
      Q[node][2]=Q[node][3];
      Q[node][3]=tmp;
    }
    return ;
      }


       query(2 * node +1, b, (b + e) / 2, i, j,ch);
      query(2 * node + 2, (b + e) / 2 + 1, e, i, j,ch);


    Q[node][0]=Q[2*node+1][0] + Q[2*node+2][0];
    Q[node][1]=Q[2*node+1][1] + Q[2*node+2][1];
    Q[node][2]=Q[2*node+1][2] + Q[2*node+2][2];
    Q[node][3]=Q[2*node+1][3] + Q[2*node+2][3];
    return ;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a specific question here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your algorithm correctly, you are using the L array to keep track of whether a a range of points needs to be flipped or not, but deferring the actual flip until it becomes necessary.

In this case, I think there might be a problem with the lines:

```
void query(int node, int b, int e, int i, int j, char ch)
{
  if(L[node][0]!=0 || L[node][1]!=0)
  {
    if(b!=e){
      L[2*node+1][0]=L[node][0];
      L[2*node+1][1]=L[node][1];
      L[2*node+2][0]=L[node][0];
      L[2*node+2][1]=L[node][1];
    }
```

Suppose L[node][0] was 1, and L[2*node+1][0] was already 1.  This means that some previous step wanted to flip the nodes at 2*node+1, and then this step also wants to flip these nodes.  These flips should cancel out and L[2*node+1][0] should become zero.

I think you should change these lines to use xor so that a double flip will cancel:

```
void query(int node, int b, int e, int i, int j, char ch)
{
  if(L[node][0]!=0 || L[node][1]!=0)
  {
    if(b!=e){
      L[2*node+1][0]^=L[node][0];
      L[2*node+1][1]^=L[node][1];
      L[2*node+2][0]^=L[node][0];
      L[2*node+2][1]^=L[node][1];
    }
```

(Or perhaps I have misunderstood the approach!)

Comment: yes, you are right I missed that step but instead of ^ it should be + as per my approach.

Comment: @Hapie, you should be able to see the check mark on the left of the screen under the voting arrows and the post score

Comment: @dsolimano : I had done already please post after checking :)

Comment: @Hapie I think we had a race condition - I saw your comment, answered, and then when I refreshed saw that you had accepted.

Comment: @dsolimano I had removed the code from here because it can be copied by others which is wrong and you put the code back here . please keep the query function and initialize there and remove rest so that alteast others try to code themselves rather than copying from here :)